# How to boot Debian Testing when grub_env_export symbol not found?

Tags: linux, debian, grub, grub2

After a recent run of

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and subsequent reboot, I get just:

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: symbol not found: 'grub_env_export'.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Is there a way of booting the computer *without* a live CD/USB?

Answer (score 1):

On [this discussion thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742655), user Paul Davis says:

> The problem from what I can tell is that grub2 was upgraded, however,
>   during the install the grub image was installed to the wrong hard
>   drive. The old grub2 image can't load the new grub2 modules so it
>   fails. Luckily there is a really easy way to fix it, just boot from
>   the hard drive that mistakenly had the new grub2 image installed on
>   it. You can either change the boot drive in the BIOS directly or most
>   BIOS's have a boot menu that lets you decide which drive to boot from.
>   Once you get back into Ubuntu you can just do a sudo grub-install
>   /dev/sdx where sdx is the drive that the the grub2 image should have
>   been installed on to get everything fixed to the way it should have
>   been.